# Tensorflow Calculates the cosine distance of two Tensors in a dimension

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to implement this paper : "Multi-Perspective Sentence Similarity Modeling with CNN". I have a trouble in Algorithm 1 and Algorithm 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsYCu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncx1m.png)
This is the first time for me to write a TensorFlow code.

```
        with tf.variable_scope("algo_1"):
        for i, pooling in enumerate([K.max, K.min, K.mean]):
            regM1, regM2 = None, None
            for j, ws in enumerate(self.wss):
                for k, atten_embed in enumerate(self.atten_embdding):
                    #conv ->(None, ws, 1, 300)    regM1/2  --> (None, 3,1,300)
                    conv = self.building_block_A(atten_embed, ws)
                    pool = pooling(conv, 1, keepdims=True)
                    #conv = tf.squeeze(conv, axis=[0, 2])
                    if j == 0:
                        if k == 0:
                            regM1 = pool
                        else:
                            regM2 = pool
                    else:
                        if k == 0:
                            regM1 = tf.concat([regM1, pool], 1)
                        else:
                            regM2 = tf.concat([regM2, pool], 1)
```

so regM1 and regM2 is the CNN result of sentence1 and sentence2. How can I cal the similarity of them according to algorithm 1 and 2.

the shape of regM1/2 is [batch_size, 3, 1, 300], where 3 is the number of ws, 300 is the number of filters. I don't know how to cal the cosine distance between two Tensor with batch.